# What is a good free font management tool for linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, font-management

I've been trying to find a font management tool that is free, but all solutions are comercial.
Is there a good font management tool that is free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unsure about the *goodness*, but **[Fontmatrix](http://fontmatrix.net/)** is a free & open–source font manager that is available to Linux (as well as to Windows & OS X). Its searching and font comparison tools seem to be comprehensive.

The UI may be a bit rough on the edges and development isn't exactly rapid (last update 1½ years ago), but at least the price is right!

Screenshot *(courtesy of Fontmatrix):*

[image: Fontmatrix screenshot]

Comment: I've installed (and uninstalled) Fontmatrix 0.9 on Kubuntu 14.04.1 and it looked nothing like screenshot You are offering.
Furthermore, developer's site doesnt offer any screenshots; no wonder because it is dated yr 2008.
Maybe it is time to fresh-up?

Comment: This also doesn't build on Linux any more. Looks like it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 6):

There's **font-manager** which is available for most linux distributions shipping with Gnome. It isn't installed by default but should be available to install through the package management system.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have tried both Font Matrix and Font Manager. These appear to be the only two that are easy acquire.  While Font Manager is more stable, it is lacking in features and very limited in scope. Font Matrix is slightly better in this but has choked on me several times in a fresh install of Linux Mint. Still, I will stick with Font Matrix as the slightly more feature rich and category standard in features and function compared to what I am used to in the OSX / Windows worlds.