# Photoshop: Is it possible to display ONE style of a font in the drop down?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-management

In photoshop, I'll click the font drop down menu. If a font has multiple styles it displays all of them. Example: Ariel bold, Ariel italic, Ariel bold italic, etc. Yet the option is repetitive and rather annoying; the style choices are listed again in the drop down box directly right of the font drop down. Ideally I'd like to click 'Ariel' and then browse the styles of said font in the second drop down.  Is there a way to condense the fonts making my list more manageable? Or is it literally just a repetitive option....

Comment: This is off-topic as it's tech support. However **I AGREE**. I've filed bug reports, and posted on feedback.photoshop.com about this issue. There should be a way to disable the display of every single font face in the menu. Unfortunately, until they fix it at Adobe, there's nothing you can do except use an older version of Photoshop.

Comment: Because Adobe's software is notoriously rather rubbish for this, people often a) use 'font management' software for browsing fonts (e.g. [Mac](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/), [Windows](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/), [Linux](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/)), and b) often uninstall fonts they don't/won't use to make their font lists more manageable.

Comment: apologies for the off topic post. This is my first question in my life via internet. I've normally just researched my concerns. Thank you for your polite and timely replies.